# python execute shell command and continue without waiting and check if running before executing

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I need to execute two other python scripts from another one.
commands look like this:

# python send.py

# python wait.py

This will happen in a loop that will sleep for 1 minute then re-run.

**Before executing the commands to start the other scripts I need to make sure they are not still running.**

Comment: Have you tried using the subprocess module?

Comment: Why can't you `import` the two scripts and call the functions inside of them normally?

Comment: Because the two apps will be rewritten in a different language at some point.

Comment: subprocess seems to wait for the application to finish before continuing. I need to just execute and move on.

Comment: @larsmans, it does, if you do not explictly use `Popen`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) to do that, example:

```
import subprocess

command1 = subprocess.Popen(['command1', 'args1', 'arg2'])
command2 = subprocess.Popen(['command2', 'args1', 'arg2'])
```

if you need to retrieve the output do the following:

```
command1.wait()
print command1.stdout
```

Example run:

```
sleep = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '60'])
sleep.wait()
print sleep.stdout  # sleep outputs nothing but...
print sleep.returncode  # you get the exit value
```

Comment: `stdout` is only meaningful when `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` is passed to the `Popen` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import commands
from subprocess import Popen

while True:
  t_ph = commands.getstatusoutput('ps -eo pid,args | grep script1.py | grep -v service | grep -v init.d | grep -v grep | cut -c1-6')
  t_fb = commands.getstatusoutput('ps -eo pid,args | grep script2.py | grep -v service | grep -v init.d | grep -v grep | cut -c1-6')

  if t_ph[1] == '':
    r_ph = Popen(["python", "script1.py"])

  if t_fb[1] == '':
    r_fb = Popen(["python", "script2.py"])

  time.sleep(60)
```

or

```
import time
import commands
from subprocess import Popen

r_ph = False
r_fb = False

while True:

  if r_ph == False:
    r_ph = Popen(["python", "script1.py"])
  else:
    if r_ph.poll():
      r_ph = Popen(["python", "script1.py"])

  if r_fb == False:
    r_fb = Popen(["python", "script2.py"])
  else:
    if r_fb.poll():
      r_fb = Popen(["python", "script2.py"])

  time.sleep(60)
```

*this could be written a bit better but it works*